# Show the roots of the quadratic equation $z^2 +bz+ c = 0$ lie in or on the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, polynomials, roots, quadratics

So I need a little help with the following:
Considering separately the cases of real and complex roots show that the roots of the quadratic equation  $z^2 +bz+ c = 0$ lie in or on the unit circle (i.e. $|z_{i}|\leq 1$) if and only if $|c|\leq1$ and $|b|\leq 1+c$, where $b$ and $c$ are real coefficients.

I showed both sides of the relation for real roots, but now I am stuck on the complex case. Any ideas?

Comment: Are $b,c$ real or complex? Presumably $c$ is real because of that inequality. But what about $b$?

Comment: b, c are real, sorry

Comment: So you mean "inside the closed unit disk"? The "unit circle" – as I know it – is the the set $\{ z : |z| = 1 \}$.

Comment: yes, what I mean by on or in the unit circle is $|z|\leq 1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since, roots are complex $b^2 \leq4c$. Hence, $c\geq0$. The roots are $$z_1,_2=(-b\pm i \sqrt{(4c-b^2)})/2$$We first assume roots lie in unit circle. Hence,$|z|^2\leq1$ which implies $$(b^2+(4c-b^2))/4\leq1\implies c\leq1, i.e, |c|\leq1$$ Also, $(1-c)^2\geq0\implies(1-c)^2+4c\geq4c\implies(1+c)^2\geq4c\implies(1+c)^2\geq b^2\implies|b|\leq 1+c$

Now, let's prove the other direction. Assume the conditions hold. Then,$$|z|^2=(b^2+(4c-b^2))/4=c\leq1$$ $$\implies |z|\leq1$$

Answer (score 0):

We can consider that $c\geq 0$, because if $c<0$ then the equation has real roots. Now you have that

$$z=\cfrac{-b\pm i\sqrt{4c-b^2}}{2}$$

and so

$$|z|=\sqrt{\cfrac{b^2}{4}+\cfrac{4c-b^2}{4}}=\sqrt{c}\leq 1\Leftrightarrow c\leq 1$$

Comment: The LHS should be $|z|^2$? – Also this would only be true if $4c - b^2 \ge 0$, i.e. the equation has two imaginary conjugate roots?

Comment: He said that he has solved the case that the equation has real roots

Comment: Yeah you are right. I didn't understand it initially.

Comment: Fine but you need to add something like: So if $|z|\le1$ we have $c\le1$. Since $(c-1)^2\ge0$ we also have $4c\le(c+1)^2$ and so $|b|\le c+1$. Conversely, if $c\le1$ then $|z|\le1$.

Comment: Oh! Now I saw that you have to prove the inverse. I' ll see it in the morning.

Answer (score -2):

For the direct part, the equation $z^2+bz+c=0$ always has roots in complex field $\mathbb C$. Let $p$ and $q=\bar p$ are its roots, then product of roots is $p\bar p=c→|p|^2=|c|→|p|\le 1$. Thus, both roots lie within $|z|\le 1$.

For the converse part, assume that $z^2+bz+c=0$ has both its roots inside $|z|\le 1$. Let $p$ and $q$ be the roots s.t. $|p|\le 1$ and $|q|\le 1$ which gives $|p||q|\le 1$ or $|pq|\le 1$ i.e. $|c|\le 1$.

Also, if $p=u+iv$ then $q=u-iv$ then $|b|\le 1+c$ implies $2u\le 1+u^2 + v^2$ or $(u-1)^2+v^2\ge 0$ which holds for all real $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Why downvote....I dnt understand.

Comment: If you downvote, then please justify it..

Comment: I think this is against the rules and ethics of MSE, if a downvoter tries to keep the mystery of the reason of his/her downvote. It is also a disrespect of someone who genuinly tries to post answer in order to learn and improve his/her mathematical skills.

Comment: @dxiv.. thanks for your concern..I made an edit. Kindly check. Thanks again.

Comment: `|b| <= 1 + c implies 2 u <= 1 + u^2 + v^2`. First, that's `2 |u|` not just `2 u`. Then, it `is equivalent to` rather than just `implies` (because you need an equivalence there to complete the proof). And it is an equivalence indeed, since at that point you know that $|b| = |-(p + q)| = 2 |u|$ and $1 + c = 1 + p q = 1 + u^2 + v^2$.