# Region of the coefficients of a quadratic equation that cause the roots of it to be in the unit disk

Tags: quadratics, signal-processing

From Simon Haykin's Adaptive Filter Theory: consider the characteristic equation is $1+a_{1}z^{-1}+a_{2}z^{-2}=0$, then for the roots to be inside the unit circle (or in the unit disk), the coefficients of the quadratic must satisfy the following conditions: **$-1\le a_{1}+a_{2}$**, **$-1\le a_{2}-a_{1}$**, and **$-1\le a_{2}\le 1$**.

I could figure this out some of the way. For complex roots it follows that the coefficients lie in the region defined by the intersection of $4a_2>a_{1}^2$ and $a_2<1$. For real roots, I could prove that $|a_2|<1$, and obviously $4a_2\le a_{1}^2$. But I cannot figure out how the line boundaries of the region can be derived. Can someone please explain how?

Comment: Related to this one I found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839654/show-the-roots-of-the-quadratic-equation-z2-bz-c-0-lie-in-or-on-the-unit

Comment: Discovered a typo in the third boundary condition on the coefficients. I've also posted the corrected question here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/69927/region-of-the-coefficients-of-a-quadratic-equation-that-cause-the-roots-of-it-to. If someone can kindly edit my question to fix the typo here, I'd appreciate it. I don't have enough rep to do it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the quadratic equation

$$z= \dfrac{-a_1}{2} \pm \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{a_1}{2}\right)^2 - a_2} $$

For the greater real root and the upper boundary on the real line

$$\begin{align*} 1 &\ge \dfrac{-a_1}{2} + \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{a_1}{2}\right)^2 - a_2}\\
\\
1 + \dfrac{a_1}{2} &\ge + \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{a_1}{2}\right)^2 - a_2}\\
\\
1 + a_1 + \left(\dfrac{a_1}{2}\right)^2 &\ge \left(\dfrac{a_1}{2}\right)^2 - a_2\\
\\
a_1 + a_2  &\ge -1
\end{align*}$$

For the lesser real root and the lower boundary on the real line

$$\begin{align*} -1 &\le \dfrac{-a_1}{2} - \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{a_1}{2}\right)^2 - a_2}\\
\\
-1 + \dfrac{a_1}{2} &\le - \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{a_1}{2}\right)^2 - a_2}\\
\\
-1 + a_1 + \left(\dfrac{a_1}{2}\right)^2 &\le \left(\dfrac{a_1}{2}\right)^2 - a_2\\
\\
-1 &\le a_2 -a_1 \\
\end{align*}$$

For the complex roots being inside the unit circle

$$\begin{align*} 1 &\ge \left|\dfrac{-a_1}{2} \pm i\sqrt{a_2 - \left(\dfrac{a_1}{2}\right)^2}\right|\\
\\
1 &\ge \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{a_1}{2}\right)^2 + a_2 - \left(\dfrac{a_1}{2}\right)^2} \\
\\
1 &\ge \sqrt{a_2}\\
\\
1^2 &\ge \left(\sqrt{a_2}\right)^2\\
\\
1 &\ge |a_2|\\
\\
-1 &\le a_2 \le 1 \\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks for answering! For those that are interested, there is another interesting approach in an answer to the same question I posted on dsp.stackexchange (link in comments to the question above).